# Delete document but keep meta

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, splistitem

I've a document library with a lot of documents.
The documents are in an other program and we 'd like remove the document from sharepoint and replaces by a link to the document in the other program.

Do you know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a list view of the document library, with all columns, and export it into Excel. In Excel you can then use formulas to create the URL for the correct link.

Adjust the Excel file to contain only the columns you want in the list. Then create a new list from the Excel file.

After that, you can delete the document library.

If you want to keep some documents and just make others into links, there are several options.

- you could add a list item content type with the desired fields to the document library
- or you could add a URL column to the document content type and populate it with the desired URL. Then overwrite each document with an empty file, so the original document is no longer there.

Comment: and there are no way to keep the document library?Because all documents wont be replace and it's more easyer for the client to keep all at the same place

Comment: I added another suggestion

Comment: Thanks i think the second proposition to replace by an empty file seems to be the easyiest.

Comment: I've an issue, how to add a list content type to a document library? The second solution resolve the size but not the treeshold with x files